# Range: bytes 0- FAILS in Apache 2.2.23

Tags: linux, apache

I'm running plesk 9.5.2 on Centos 5 and this apache version:

```
# apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Sep 26 2012 00:02:01
```

Trying to serve some mp4 files, I've setup mime types correctly but I'm getting this weird behaviour:

```
#  curl -I  -s iated.org/inted/video_data/promo.mp4                    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 16:09:48 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sun, 28 Sep 2014 09:44:30 GMT
ETag: "21f0070-13079ae-5041cff289b80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 19954094
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Which is OK. Thats what IE10 is requesting. However Firefox and Chrome are doing something fancier and set Content-Range bytes:0- like:

```
#  curl -I -H "Range: bytes=0-" -s iated.org/inted/video_data/promo.mp4
```

Than returns nothing. Void.

Range requests works otherwise well:

```
# curl -I -H "Range: bytes=1-" -s iated.org/inted/video_data/promo.mp4                          
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Date: Mon, 29 Sep 2014 16:08:41 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.23 (CentOS)
Last-Modified: Sun, 28 Sep 2014 09:44:30 GMT
ETag: "21f0070-13079ae-5041cff289b80"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 19954093
X-Powered-By: PleskLin
Content-Range: bytes 1-19954093/19954094
Content-Type: video/mp4
```

Any idea why apache is panicking with **Range: bytes 0-** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating Apache to 2.2.27 solved the issue.